# output video has black..whats wrong in this command?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

i want add text over video and i am using ffmpeg android  lib but edited successfully but output video shows me black screen only

```java
String addtextcommand[] = {
  "-i",
  inputpath,
  "-strict",
  "-2",
  "-vf",
  "drawtext=text=\'onLine1\': fontcolor=white", "-map", "0:a",
  "-codec:v", "libx264", "-codec:a", "copy",
  output
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to give you and solution I prefer to figure out your command and find a solution by your self I m going to explain you command here

```
-i inputpath  --> for Input (Video/GIF/IMAGES/MUSIC)

 -strict -2   --> strictly conform to all the things in the spec no matter what consequences -2 for experimental 


-vf  --> for videofilter alternativaly you can use -filter_complex



drawtext=text='onLine1': fontcolor=white  --> for draw text over on any med file like image or video

-map 0:a --> to map out with 1'st input auido 0:a stands for 1'st input audio


-codec:v  --> for video codec

libx264    ---> specify video codec
-codec:a  copy --> for audio codec , here you get audio codec from input  copy stand s fro get codc from input

output --> final Output
```

try below code:

```
-i video.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text=Vinesh Chauhan:fontcolor=#000000:fontsize=14:x=43:y=103:fontfile=FACEBOLF.OTF" -y output.mp4
```

for android your command should be

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i",""+inputpath, "-filter_complex", "drawtext=text=Vinesh Chauhan:fontcolor=#000000:fontsize=14:x=43:y=103:fontfile="+fontPATH, "-y" ,""+outputpath};
```

now i think you can find your solution by your self if any query comment below will surely help you

Comment: hii vinesh can you help me..i want add image and text on same video at same. Is this possible in ffmpeg..i am trying my self using this command..if anything wrong correct it.

Comment: String  imgtxtcmd[]=new String[]{"-i", inputpath ,"-i",imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h" +" "+ "drawtext=text=Vikram Dulagach:fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=64:x=533:y=503:fontfile="+"/sdcard/retro.ttf", "-y" ,"-codec:a", "copy",output};

Comment: Hello there I am an android application Developer . Looking fow a freelancer work. i can develop video editing apps using ffmepg, like collage video maker,  Mv Master, Cropper , trimmer, stickers on vide etc so if anyone wants to do let me know

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `"-map", "0:a"` you are ignoring video from `inputpath`. Try command without that.